# Realm notification block returns unmodified value

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I insert 6 objects into a realm entity each time. In the notifications, i get the insertions correct. But the modifications values is unexpected as i don't do any modifications.

```
var listNotificationToken = listResults?.addNotificationBlock({ [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        guard let tableView = self!.myListTableView else { return }
        switch changes {
        case .Initial:
            tableView.reloadData()
            break
        case .Update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let modifications):
            print("Reload - \(deletions) - \(insertions) - \(modifications)")
            tableView.beginUpdates()
                for insertIndex in insertions {
                    tableView.insertSections(NSIndexSet(index: insertIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
                for deleteIndex in deletions {
                    tableView.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: deleteIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
                for reloadIndex in modifications {
                    tableView.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: reloadIndex), withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                }
                tableView.endUpdates()
            break
        case .Error(let error):
            print("\(error)")
            break
        }
    })
```

The results are as follows.

```
Reload - [] - [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] - []
Reload - [] - [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11] - [4, 5]
Reload - [] - [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17] - [4, 5, 10, 11]
Reload - [] - [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23] - [0, 1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
Reload - [] - [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29] - [3, 23]
Reload - [] - [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35] - [0, 1, 22]
Reload - [] - [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41] - [0, 1, 22, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]
Reload - [] - [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47] - [0, 1, 22, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41]
```

Any help in debugging this?

EDIT:

My Model Class:

```
class TalksList: Object {
 dynamic var identifier : String? = nil
 dynamic var isSynced: Bool = true
 dynamic var talkType : String? = nil
 dynamic var title : String? = nil

...

  override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
      return "identifier"
  }

  class func saveObjectsFromArray(rawArray: NSArray) {
      let dbArray = [TalksList]()

      for rawObject in rawArray {
          let talkListObject = TalksList()

          talkListObject.isSynced = true
          talkListObject.identifier   = rawObject["_id"] as? String
          ...
          dbArray.append(talkListObject)
      }            

      try! realmInstance.write({
         realmInstance.add(dbArray, update: true)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code for the modification?

Comment: Can you please also share the model classes involved?

Comment: @bdash I have added the model class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Realm.add(_:update:)` will result in an object being inserted if no existing object exists with the same primary key, or modified if an existing object does exist. The modifications you're seeing in your collection notification block are likely generated as a result of `Realm.add(_:update:)` modifying an existing object.

Note that this also applies to any relationships your object has with other managed objects. If the related objects have a primary key defined then they too will be updated if they already exist. This will result in any objects that they're already related to being marked as modified.

Comment: Yeah i get it. But sometimes, even if im not modifying, i get notifications.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not modifying" the objects? You've not shared what data you're feeding in to your `saveObjectsFromArray` method so it's impossible to tell what output to expect. Note that passing data for an object that's identical to an object that exists in the Realm will still be considered a modification. If you don't want a notification in that case, you should avoid doing a needless write.

Comment: I have the 'identifier' as a primary key. Each time, I generate 6 new objects with unique primary keys which are not in the db. When i save these new objects, i get the insertions notification as expected. But i haven't added any objects with old identifiers. But still i get notifications for modifications.

Comment: Also i only add 6 elements each time. So in the notification, the number of insertions + modifications should be 6. But from the above output you can see its different.

Comment: Does your model class include any relationships with other model classes (i.e., any properties that are instances of other model classes, or `RLMArray`)?

Comment: Yes. Uff.. Now i get it. Thank you very much. Didn't think about this.

Comment: Happy to hear that you got to the bottom of it. I revised my answer to touch on this point.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid notifications for linked object changes? Refer this post. This will be a serious issue i guess https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3494

Comment: There's not at this time. If you feel there should be please file a new GitHub issue outlining why you believe this is important.